# Error when trying to create OPC server

Tags: c#, opc

I am trying to create OPC server in my Winforms program using opcdaauto.dll.

```
public OPCAutomation.OPCServer ConnectedOPCServer = new OPCAutomation.OPCServer();
```

But I am getting following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  HResult=-2147221164
  Message=Načítání objektu pro vytváření tříd modelu COM pro komponentu s identifikátorem CLSID {28E68F9A-8D75-11D1-8DC3-3C302A000000} se nezdařilo kvůli následující chybě : 80040154 Třída není zaregistrována (Výjimka na základě hodnoty HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
  Source=VP_OPC_Client
  ErrorCode=-2147221164
  StackTrace:
   v OPC_Client.frmMain.OPCConnect() v C:\Users\***\Desktop\OPC_Client\frmMain.cs:řádek 60
  InnerException:
```

[image]

I successfully registered opcdaauto.dll with regsvr32.exe before.

What can I do to register this class 28E68F9A-8D75-11D1-8DC3-3C302A000000?

Comment: I can't understand the error, but try adding the dll to the GAC (through Gacutil)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect remote OPC Server using opcdaauto.dll using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874772/how-to-connect-remote-opc-server-using-opcdaauto-dll-using-c)